# My user home directories disappeared after a move command

Tags: mv, recovery

I was trying to move some files and following a post here on the forum  I ran the follow command, but an error came and I hit Ctrl+C and my /desktop /documents /music folders and its contents are gone.

```
fabio@thinkpad-x250:~$ sudo mv /opt/languagetool/LanguageTool-*/ * ..
mv: inter-device move failed: 'LanguageTool-5.4' to '../LanguageTool-5.4'; unable to remove target: Directory not empty
^C
fabio@thinkpad-x250:~$ ls
LanguageTool-5.4  pictures  public  tagspaces  templates  tlp.txt  videos
```

Please, I need help!

Comment: I just perform a search on the system using cat fish and found the directories on the /home folder. So Im coping it back. For some reason I cant move to my user folder. Should I worry about any other file? Im on Linux Mint.

Comment: The lone `*` in `sudo mv /opt/languagetool/LanguageTool-*/ * ..` expands to all non-hidden files (directory is also a file) in the current working directory; and `..` means the parent directory of the current working directory. What the command does strongly depends on the current working directory. Judging by the prompt the current working directory was your home directory (`~`). This is not an answer because I don't know what the question is. There are questions in your comment but not in the body of the "question". Running (with `sudo`!) a command you don't understand is asking for trouble.

Comment: It seems you did something to fix, not everything went well. What does "For some reason I cant move to my user folder" mean? What is the error message from what exact command? Please [edit] and update the question. If you can, post exact commands (possibly with prompts revealing the current directory at the time), error messages and such, so we can imagine the *current* situation.